# My hydrangea is just stems, can it be saved?

Tags: diseases, hydrangea, recovery

My hydrangea plant is small. Had two flowers and full leaves. Prior to pruning the drying flowers the leaves started curling and drying in a dark green variation. You can see the remainder on the soil. Every leaf that has grown in starts growing like that immediately, and falls off right away. It has been in this state (stem only) for about 2 weeks now, and I have no idea if it can be saved or not. Any help would be much appreciated! It is hard to find the correct issue online (even the drying leaves, none of my searches rendered anything similar to what was happening to the leaves).

[image: sad stemmy hydrangea]

Comment: Hydrangeas are outside plants.  Why is it inside? Please add more detail